# Slow SCP tranfers over IPv6 VPN IPSec which has IPv4 private subnets

Tags: vpn, ipv6, scp, ipsec

I have 2 hosts connected with IPv6 VPN. I am using IPv4 internal addresses for machines connected internally and use subnets addressed for these in ipv4. When a host wants to scp a 1 Gig file pull from a remote machine ( with ipv4 internal ip ), the transfer is terribly slow 20 kbps. Push from the remote machine to the host shows the transfer is stalled and becomes slower from 2MBps to 20 kbps. All the other SCP transfers work fine.
Any ideas why this slow transfer one way?

ipsec.conf:
conn net-net
   type=tunnel
   keyexchange=ikev2
   left=3ffe:80c0:22c:803c:215:17ff:fed3:202
   leftsubnet=10.0.1.7/27,10.0.2.7/27
   leftcert=hostCert.pem
   right=3ffe:80c0:22c:803c:215:17ff:fed3:197
   rightsubnet=10.0.1.14/27,10.0.2.14/27
   auto=start

Comment: Those IPv6 addresses haven't been valid for years. How are you sending _any_ traffic?!

Comment: Hi, these IPv6 are assigned by me on the hosts and use it within company LANs. Is there any issue with these IPv6 addresses? Main issue is the slow SCP transfer from a remote m/c only on one direction.